# Using IndexedDB as an in-browser cache

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, database, cache

In my site:

- Users have many Activities
- Each Activity has encoded_polyline data
- I display these encoded_polylines on a map

I want to use IndexedDB (via [Dexie](https://dexie.org/)) as an in-browser cache so that they don't need to re-download their full Activity set every time they view their map. I've never used IndexedDB before, so I don't know if I'm doing anything silly or overlooking any edge cases.

---

Here's a high-level description of what I think the overall process is:

- Figure out what exists on the server
- Remove anything that is present in IndexedDB but is not present on the server
- Figure out what exists in IndexedDB
- Request only the data missing in IndexedDB
- Store the new data in IndexedDB
- Query all of the data out of IndexedDB

Throughout all of this, we need to be focusing on *this user*. A person might view many people's pages, and therefore have a copy of many people's data in IndexedDB. So the queries to the server and IndexedDB need to be aware of which User ID is being referenced.

---

Here's the English Language version of what I decided to do:

- Collect all of this User's Activty IDs from the server
- Remove anything in IndexedDB that shouldn't be there (stuff deleted from the site that might still exist in IndexedDB)
- Collect all of this User's Activty IDs from IndexedDB
- Filter out anything that's present in IndexedDB and the server
- If there are no new encoded_polylines to retrieve then `putItemsFromIndexeddbOnMap` (described below)
- If there are new encoded_polylines to retrieve: retrieve those from the server, then store them in IndexedDB, then `putItemsFromIndexeddbOnMap`

For putItemsFromIndexeddbOnMap:

- Get all of this user's encoded_polylines from IndexedDB
- Push that data into an array
- Display that array of data on the map

---

Here's the JavaScript code that does what I've explained above (with some ERB because this JavaScript is embedded in a Rails view):

```js
var db = new Dexie("db_name");
db.version(1).stores({ activities: "id,user_id" });
db.open();

// get this user's activity IDs from the server
fetch('/users/' + <%= @user.id %> + '/activity_ids.json', { credentials: 'same-origin' }
).then(response => { return response.json() }
).then(activityIdsJson => {
  // remove items from IndexedDB for this user that are not in activityIdsJson
  // this keeps data that was deleted in the site from sticking around in IndexedDB
  db.activities
    .where('id')
    .noneOf(activityIdsJson)
    .and(function(item) { return item.user_id === <%= @user.id %> })
    .keys()
    .then(removeActivityIds => {
      db.activities.bulkDelete(removeActivityIds);
    });

  // get this user's existing activity IDs out of IndexedDB
  db.activities.where({user_id: <%= @user.id %>}).primaryKeys(function(primaryKeys) {
    // filter out the activity IDs that are already in IndexedDB
    var neededIds = activityIdsJson.filter((id) => !primaryKeys.includes(id));

    if(Array.isArray(neededIds) && neededIds.length === 0) {
      // we do not need to request any new data so query IndexedDB directly
      putItemsFromIndexeddbOnMap();
    } else if(Array.isArray(neededIds)) {
      if(neededIds.equals(activityIdsJson)) {
        // we need all data so do not pass the `only` param
        neededIds = [];
      }

      // get new data (encoded_polylines for display on the map)
      fetch('/users/' + <%= @user.id %> + '/encoded_polylines.json?only=' + neededIds, { credentials: 'same-origin' }
      ).then(response => { return response.json() }
      ).then(newEncodedPolylinesJson => {
        // store the new encoded_polylines in IndexedDB
        db.activities.bulkPut(newEncodedPolylinesJson).then(_unused => {
          // pull all encoded_polylines out of IndexedDB
          putItemsFromIndexeddbOnMap();
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

function putItemsFromIndexeddbOnMap() {
  var featureCollection = [];

  db.activities.where({user_id: <%= @user.id %>}).each(activity => {
    featureCollection.push({
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: polyline.toGeoJSON(activity['encoded_polyline'])
    });
  }).then(function() {
    // if there are any polylines, add them to the map
    if(featureCollection.length > 0) {
      if(map.isStyleLoaded()) {
        // map has fully loaded so add polylines to the map
        addPolylineLayer(featureCollection);
      } else {
        // map is still loading, so wait for that to complete
        map.on('style.load', addPolylineLayer(featureCollection));
      }
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error.stack || error);
  });
}

function addPolylineLayer(data) {
  map.addSource('polylineCollection', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: data
    }
  });
  map.addLayer({
    id: 'polylineCollection',
    type: 'line',
    source: 'polylineCollection'
  });
}
```

Can you review my code for best practices?

Answer (score 2):

Overall this code looks fine, except I don't see much for error handling. I see a `catch` block in the `putItemsFromIndexeddbOnMap()` function but it either outputs the stack or else the error. What happens if the server responses from the calls to `fetch()` yield client side errors (e.g. 403, 404, etc) or server-side errors (e.g. 500)? Should the user see a "friendly" message, informing him/her as to what happened?

There are a few simplifications mentioned below. You could also consider using [asynchronous functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) along with the `await` operator on promises to remove the `.then()` blocks.

---

This code makes decent use of arrow functions, but some of them can be simplified - for instance, after the `fetch()` call to get activity ids there is this line:

> ```
> ).then(response => { return response.json() }
> ```

An arrow function with a single statement doesn't need curly brackets or a `return` statement - it can simply be:

```
).then(response => response.json()
```

And similarly, there is an identical line after the call to `fetch()` for encoded polylines - that can also be simplified.

There is also an anonymous function that could be simplified using an arrow function:

> ```
> .and(function(item) { return item.user_id === <%= @user.id %> })
> ```

---

There are a few anonymous functions that could be simplified to function references

For example:

> ```
> .then(removeActivityIds => {
>   db.activities.bulkDelete(removeActivityIds);
> });
> ```

Should be simplifiable to

```
.then(db.activities.bulkDelete)
```

Though you might have to make a [bound function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Creating_a_bound_function) with [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

And this block:

> ```
> db.activities.bulkPut(newEncodedPolylinesJson).then(_unused => {
>       // pull all encoded_polylines out of IndexedDB
>       putItemsFromIndexeddbOnMap();
>     });
> ```

Can be simplified to

```
db.activities.bulkPut(newEncodedPolylinesJson)
    .then(putItemsFromIndexeddbOnMap); // pull all encoded_polylines out of IndexedDB
```

---

On the line below, `Array.isArray()` seems to be the wrong place to check for an array:

> ```
>  if(Array.isArray(neededIds) && neededIds.length === 0) {
> ```

Given that it is returned from:

> ```
> var neededIds = activityIdsJson.filter((id) => !primaryKeys.includes(id));
> ```

And [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns "*A new array with the elements that pass the test. If no elements pass the test, an empty array will be returned.*"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Return_value)</sup>

So perhaps the check should really be on `activityIdsJson` to see if that is an array.

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Return_value</sub>